# WiFi Issue (Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174)

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

In addition to Windows, I also have Kubuntu 22.04. In Kubuntu I faced the problem on my laptop (Xiaomi Redmibook 14 RyzenEdition) - OS can't see network card. I've found the guide [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343) but this information is not relevant. Current [repository](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0) has a lot of directories. Do I have to download all of it?

What did I do:

1. downloaded linux-firmware
2. Create a directory (/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/)
3. Downloaded board.bin, board-2.bin and firmware-4.bin

**dmesg:**

```
[    3.254464] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: invalid firmware magic
[    3.254554] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Failed to find firmware-N.bin (N between 2 and 6) from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0: -2
[    3.254598] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[    3.254623] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

**ls lib/firmware/ath10k**

QCA4019  QCA6174  QCA9377  QCA9887  QCA9888  QCA988X  QCA9984  QCA99X0  WCN3990

and QCA6174 has hw2.1 , hw3.0.

**ls hw3.0**

board-2.bin  board.bin  firmware-4.bin

Still doesn't work(

after reinstall linux-firmware

```
board-2.bin  
firmware-4.bin  
firmware-sdio-6.bin          
notice_ath10k_firmware-6.txt 
board.bin    
firmware-6.bin 
notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt  
notice_ath10k_firmware-sdio-6
```

--

```
[    3.364952] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.643853] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[    3.643862] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.644421] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 90eebefb
[    3.709239] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=11ad,subsystem-device=0847 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[    3.709488] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
[    6.966917] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt version request timed out
[    6.966927] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to setup htt: -110
[    7.047370] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not init core (-110)
[    7.047436] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139717/discussion-on-question-by-mark-baudelaire-wifi-issue-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for helping @Pilot6

**Solution:**

1. `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware`
2. `sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin`
3. Reboot, if doesn't work then

```
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/2.0/board.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
```

You can also text me. Good luck!

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: Yes, it did. But I took board.bin from another source

Comment: It is great you found the solution.